# Crash when using Voiceover

Tags: crash, voiceover, ios13, xcode11

Crash only when using Voiceover, good performance when shutting down

This only happens on XCode 11 and iOS 13

```
void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:resource:didFinishLoadingFromDataSource:) failed to return after waiting 10.000000 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode

nw_connection_receive_internal_block_invoke [C26] Receive reply failed with error "Operation canceled"

Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue
```

This is the last content that appears in the console, then the program crashes

Comment: We ended up relying on the hidden Tabbar to solve the problem, although this is not a good idea, but useful。

Answer (score 0):

I also experience a crash with both iOS 13.0 and 13.1, but with Voice Control, not VoiceOver.

For some reason, if you launch the application after Voice Control being enabled, viewDidLoad() is called right after you assign rootViewController to a window.

Normally it is called (if Voice Control disabled and at previous iOS version) from main, not after rootViewController assign.

I solved mine crash using rather a hack than a real solution like this:

```
let root = YourUIViewController()
```

This will crash on iOS 13 if Voice Control is enabled

```
window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: root)
```

This will not crash on iOS 13 with enabled Voice Control

```
let mainWindow = UIWindow()
mainWindow.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: root)
window = mainWindow
```

Looks like an iOS 13.1 bug for me. But I'm not sure if it actually is a bug or a new feature.

Also I've described my issue more detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58119107/viewdidload-being-called-after-window-rootviewcontroller-assign-when-voice-con)

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but this has no effect on me. My crash occurred when I loaded the Tabbar ViewController, and it happened a lot when the UI was updated.